# Background not working with new cucumber version

Tags: cucumber

We were using multiple backgrounds in same feature file in our implementation with cucumber "0.10.3". We are using cucumber along with protractor. We have now moved to Cucumber "1.2.1". But we are getting the following parser error:

```
(27:1): expected: #EOF, #TableRow, #DocStringSeparator, #StepLine, #TagLine, #ScenarioLine, #ScenarioOutlineLine, #Comme
nt, #Empty, got 'background:'
(57:1): expected: #EOF, #TableRow, #DocStringSeparator, #StepLine, #TagLine, #ScenarioLine, #ScenarioOutlineLine, #Comme
nt, #Empty, got 'background:'
```

Are multiple backgrounds no longer allowed?
Is there a workaround to use multiple backgrounds with the newer versions?